# Scrape product pages from E-Commerce websites

Tags: web-scraping, cookies, http-headers, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have come across a requirement to scrape product pages of some E-Commerce websites at scale [25-50 TPS]. I am taking the example of crawling amazon product pages as an example here in order to explain the problems I am facing. The API I am making use of to perform this task is Apache's **CloseableHttpClient** [in **Java**].
The code itself works as expected. But, while running the scrape at scale, I have come across quite a few Captchas and 5xx error responses from amazon [as an example]. This I believe is to be expected as amazon would have its own Anti-Bot mechanism.
In order to avoid being detected as a bot, I have tried to mimic the behaviour of various browsers [Chrome, Safari, Firefox etc]. I have considered the following parameters to avoid detection:

- Proxies
- Headers
- Cookies
- User-Agents

As an example, I have tried to mimic the behaviour of Safari browser which is as shown below:

```
GET /Gillette-Fusion-ProGlide-Refills-Cartridge/dp/B072M5FFZ5 HTTP/1.1
Cookie: session-id=147-2327656-3202211; session-id-time=2082787201l; ubid-main=131-1518884-4482131; csm-hit=tb:s-P678SHE1N3JR8AXN19XZ|1635514068722&t:1635514070717&adb:adblk_no; session-token=XDtHgEvrmW2+5c05J+Yo8vjk4yaVAf2+ZpVBtSe8c/1esqV/GGIbrYX8p8iyBqUEuVqzKM7iWhi0FQIh4rO+md/5fjJD4Wf7PRcLVMxCFzXlde/OVdPLHmi5Xq+/4Mgg2qM+t5eSjdyn9rdxv2SJ9vU6wgouHr0MYH3YRBOP/NnspXKQZBA9shS5JCdIwpc3; skin=noskin; i18n-prefs=USD; lc-main=en_US
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Host: www.amazon.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Safari/605.1.15
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

I have used a couple of proxies [in the required region], used the headers in the same order and the same case as shown above, used a list of User-Agents with a behaviour similar to the example shared above and a couple of pre-calculated cookies. Inspite of this, my success rate stands at 30-35%.

My questions here are as follows:

1. How do I go about improving the success rate of my scrapes?
2. How important is it to add a cookie? The cookie being sent by Safari has a **csm-hit** entry. Is there a way to calculate this on an ad-hoc basis?
3. Am I missing other entities [apart from headers, user-agents and proxies] that would improve my success rate?

Any help would be appreciated.